# Bind Specific Columns of Datatable to Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a `datatable` that has many columns,
now I have a `datagridview` that already have columns designed using these codes:

```
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.ColumnCount = 4;

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Number";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Quantity";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Percent";
```

Now I want to bind specific columns of my `datatable` to these columns of `datagridview`

somthing like that;

```
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "FeedName";
```

that FeedName is header of a column in `datatable`

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

this is how I fixed my problem:

```
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FeedName";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "Quantity";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Quantity";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Percent";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Percent";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Percent";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.DataSource = DTable;
```